# What is this view being used in my query?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-sql-developer, explain

I'm running `EXPLAIN PLAN` on this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.item_num, l.repl_code
FROM item_w l
JOIN item i ON l.item_num = i.item_num
LEFT JOIN item_w r ON l.item_num = r.item_num AND l.repl_code = r.whse_code
WHERE r.whse_code IS NULL 
  AND l.repl_code IN (SELECT DISTINCT whse_code FROM item_w)
  AND i.sa_item NOT LIKE 'Z%'
ORDER BY l.item_num, l.repl_code
```

The query works as desired but the plan is telling me that it is using objects named `VW_DTP_F6D0ECAD`, `VW_DTP_53909802` and `VW_DTP_69531A7E` which I'm not able to find in my database.

What are these objects and how are they being created?

Comment: Edit your question with the full query plan.

Comment: Jonathan Lewis to the rescue: http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2011/02/27/internal-views/

Comment: @Phil thanks for the link sorry I can't upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views starting with VW_DTP showing up in the execution plan is the result of one of the cost-based query transformations available since 11.2, called `distinct placement`.

It happens with statements using the `DISTINCT` clause, just like yours. It is an absolutely acceptable an quite obvious execution plan to join the tables and filter the rows, and **after that**, find distinct rows. However, finding distinct rows at the time of accessing the tables, **before** joining them, may be more effective, and the database may choose to transform the query based on the estimated cost.